# Delphi Berlin update 2 Win64 Compiler on Win32 Platform

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

After installing Delphi Berlin update 2 when I compile targeting win64 Release or Debug Platform - Normal. The compiler generates a win32 application instead of win64. Configuration of the compiler Win64-Normal profile:

[image]

Answer from compiler output should be in the target folder:

[image]

Instead a win32/Debug or win32/Release folder has been created and it contains the executable in win32 format.

This happens also with libraries ...

Comment: Works here as expected.

Comment: Please submit an issue to the vendor.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue here. Please [edit] to include what you have for Project->Options->Delphi Compiler->Output directory with that target selected.

Comment: Resolved The problem was with some settings passed from one release to the other. Making a fresh install everything goes Fine. Probably a third party library with its directory in the Path environment.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved uninstalling Delphi and reinstalling without porting the settings. Probably (well surely) I had a not correct path setting from a third party library vendor install that caused the problem. With a fresh install everything goes fine.